# How can I log in to Instagram using Selenium 4.14.0?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, logging, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using selenium 4.14.0 and mozilla 119.0 and GeckoDriver-v0.33.0.
Accordingly, how do I log in on Instagram? By code.

I don't know how to automatically log in to Instagram using Selenium and according to the version of the software I use.

Comment: Please take the [tour], see [ask] and go through the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code, where I have scraped the code to log in to Instagram.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# Open the Instagram login page
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")

# Find the username and password fields by their name attribute
username = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
password = driver.find_element_by_name("password")

# Enter your username and password
username.send_keys("your_username")
password.send_keys("your_password")

# Press the enter key to submit the form
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# Wait for the page to load
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

# You are now logged in to Instagram
print("Login successful!")
```

Comment: driver = webdriver.Firefox()
NameError: name 'webdriver' is not defined

Comment: Have u added the Selenium library?

Comment: How so.? Which?

Comment: I tried the code but it doesn't work

Comment: Re *"scraped the code"*: It is supposedly ***not*** the code which has been scraped? Isn't it the code which does the scraping?

Comment: Was the code generated by [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add these dependencies to your *[pom.xml](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#What_is_the_POM.3F)* file.

   ```xml
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
       <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
       <version>4.9.0</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Also add the below code in your class.

   ```python
   from selenium import webdriver
   from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

   driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
   ```

Comment: I didn't understand it very well

Comment: follow this video link :    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2VRKbEH5Js              to set up the configuration and later you can utilize the shared code for the Instagram journey.